# UIStackView Hide Animation not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I don't know what is going on but this will happened a lot of time to me. I used `UIStackView` for arranging the view and animation but when I hide the control in `UIStackView` there will be some sort of weird animation is there. Here I attached video and code.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.viewCollectionSpecies.isHidden = true
})
```

[image]

Comment: maybe its something with your constraints

Comment: what is that view that is moving diagonally? is it the view that you hide?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.viewCollectionSpecies.alpha = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
     self.viewCollectionSpecies.isHidden = true
     self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Or

```
self.viewCollectionSpecies.isHidden = true
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
     self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I already try this solution but same result i got

Comment: @chiragshah pls do try SPatel's edit, it might help

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got clue what is issue. There will be one height constraint which I need to forgot to remove after removing that constraint it work perfectly.

```
self.heightConstraint.constant = 0.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.viewCollectionSpecies.isHidden = true
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the alpha value:

```
func changeViewTo(newView: UIView, oldView: UIView) {
    newView.isHidden = false
    newView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.4, animations: {
        oldView.alpha = 0
        newView.alpha = 1
    }) { (result: Bool) in
        oldView.isHidden = true
    }
    layoutIfNeeded()
    self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: your solution not working with my animation

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's kinda hard to imagine what you want to approach with so little detail.

Comment: i need to reduce the space which is occupied by collection view if i  make alpha animation then space remaining as it is and not looks good

Comment: if you could set the alpha to 0 before animation block in your original code then it will work as expected